# Getting the previous and current number of sequence

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I have a problem on how to get the previous and current number of a sequence of integers . The problem is that everytime the previous number is same as the current (for example 15 12 16 10 9 8 0 and both are 8). Any ideas how to change it ? Thanks . Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int currentNumber;
    int input;
    int previousNumber = 0; 
    cin >> input;
    while (input > 0 && input!=0)
    {
        currentNumber = input;
        cin >> input;
        previousNumber = currentNumber;
    }

    cout << previousNumber << endl;
    cout << currentNumber << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: When  I enter  any numbers  it always shows that the current and previous number are the same. Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: @Ivo Slavev  I think that in the while statement while (input > 0 && input!=0) there is absent one sub-condition. There should be while (input > 0 && input!=0 && !( input < 0 ) ) :)

Comment: In the expression `input > 0 && input!=0`, the last part (`input != 0`) is redundant. If `input > 0` is true, then `input` is by definition can't be equal to `0`.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). By stepping through the code, line by line, you will quite quickly see *why* you have a problem. And once you know *why* then it's easier to understand how to fix it.

Comment: `previousNumber = currentNumber;` think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then what you need is the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int currentNumber  = 0;
    int previousNumber = 0;

    for (int input; std::cin >> input && input > 0; )
    {
        if (currentNumber) previousNumber = currentNumber;
        currentNumber = input;
    }

    std::cout << previousNumber << std::endl;
    std::cout << currentNumber  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```